# Example of dense subspace of $l_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

So $l_\infty$ is not separable.  So any dense subspace would be uncountable.  Any familiar space like space of continuous function, $c_0$ or $c_{00}$ space that are not dense in $l_\infty$.

So any precise example for dense linear subspace in $l_\infty$

Comment: The kernel of any dis-continuous linear functional is a dense subspace (necessarily uncountable).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Good point. I did not think that through. The space of divergent sequences cannot be linear, of course.

Comment: Did you mean a linear subspace or just a dense subset?

Comment: Sorry edited linear subspace

Answer (score 0):

An example is $l_\infty$ that is dense in $l_\infty$. For other examples you can remove a finite amount of points from $l_\infty$ and still it will be dense.

Comment: OP wants  a dense subspace. Removing a finite number of points doesn't give you  a subspace.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Of course it is a subspace XD, do you think it gets bigger by removing points?

Comment: Linear subspace.

Comment: I don't see the word linear or vector in the question though....

Comment: It is not unusual. Also it is trivial to generate a dense subset and the examples given in the questions are both linear spaces. The space of convergent sequences ($c$) is another example.

Comment: @copper.hat but then the comment about $l_\infty$ not being separable wouldn't be relevant because every real (and non trivial) vector space is not countable.

Comment: Ask the OP. It just seems trivial to me if they did not mean linear subspace.

Comment: I have edited it . It's linear dense subspace